# Form validation with required attribute when submitting from orphaned control in IE10

Tags: html, forms, validation, internet-explorer-10

In HTML5, i have [an orphaned form control](http://www.impressivewebs.com/html5-form-attribute/) submitting my form. To support IE10, i use the following:

```
jQuery(document).delegate('input[form][type="submit"], button[form][type="submit"]', 'click', function() {
  form_selector = "form#" + jQuery(this).attr("form") + "";
  console.log("submitting IE10 form from an orphaned control:" + form_selector);
  jQuery(form_selector).submit();
});
```

chrome and firefox submit without this bit of code fine and handle inputs with the required attribute as usual, stopping the submit and showing a pop-up message if any one required input is empty.

```
<input required/>
```

IE10 needs the above javascript to submit the form, HOWEVER, if any inputs with the required attribute are empty, the usual pop-up messages do not appear over the empty controls. If i move the control under the form and DO NOT USE the `submit()` function, then the pop-up messages appear fine.

any advice on how to get the pop-ups to show up when calling `submit()` in IE10?

**EDIT**: here's a jsfiddle to demo what's happening: http://jsfiddle.net/2YYvh/5/
Try it both in IE10 and chrome/firefox

Comment: To make it easier for others to help you please add more of the code here or in a jsfiddle or codeshare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the [$.trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method you can activate the `submit` button that you need to in order to fire the validation.

The following is an updated version of your example using the `.trigger`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready( function() {
        $('.btn-primary').click(function(event) {
            $("form#test_form input[type=submit]").trigger( "click" );
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>
    Try this in chrome and then in IE10
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" form="test_form">
        im outside the form
    </button>
</h2>
<div class="dashWidget autoHeight" data-pagination='true'>
    <form id="test_form">
        Leave me blank:<input type="text" value="" required />
        <input type="submit" value="im in the form!"/>
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

---

This is not directly related but is an alternative.

You could always create your own validation, for example if you want to validate an `input` of `type=email`. You could listen for the `input` event on the email field.  If HTML5 validation throws a `typeMismatch`, then override the default message with something more useful and/or sarcastic.

```
$('.email').bind('input', function () {
    //We need to reset it to blank or it will throw an invalid message.
    this.setCustomValidity('');
    if (!this.validity.valid) {
        this.setCustomValidity("Dude '" + this.value + "' is not a valid email. Try something like "+
                "jim@jboss.org. And no we are not checking if it actually works, we are just looking "+
                "for the @ sign. ");
    }
});
```

Comment: yeah, i was kind of looking for the secret call that im missing when calling submit(). If no one can answer that, i'll accept this answer.

Comment: I updated the answer. Does this fit what you are trying to do?